# Angular ui router state gets confused (closed)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 state :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('page-0', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'modules/page-0/page-zero.html',
        controller:'page0Controller'
    })
    .state('page-1', {
        url: '/:url',
        templateUrl: 'modules/page-1/page-one.html',
        controller:'page1Controller'
    })
```

When I go to `/` it goes to `page-0` for a brief time then it proceeds to `page-1`. How do I make `/` without the `params` stays at `page-0`? And when I go to `/something` it should proceed to `page-1`?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Sorry! Actually the code above works just fine, I just found a glitch on my logic.I was doing a `$state.go()` on my `page-0` controller. I am really sorry.

Comment: Are those real state names: `page-0` and `page-1`?, because I believe those are not valid names. Try with `page0` and `page1`

Comment: They're working that way. @radyz

Comment: Turned my comment into an answer for further help :)

Comment: Removed my wrong answer based on your updates to avoid further confussion then.

Comment: @radyz thank  you so much! And am really sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The two states are basically the same state `page-0` is the same as `page-1` without parameter so what you should do is merge the two state to `page` and add a default value to `url` parameter like this

```
.state('page', {
        url: '/:url',
        templateUrl: 'modules/page-1/page-one.html',
        controller:'pageController',
        params:{
           url:null
        }
 })
```

and in `pageController` check if the parameter is `null` or not like this

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(function($stateParams){
  if($stateParams.url == null){
    //do something ; pretend you are in page-0
  }else{
   //do something ; pretend you are in page-1
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**: The question was correct the first time but my answer goes to folks who kind of had the same problem the question describes.

Comment: And no, `page-0` and `page-1` are two different state.

Comment: Your answer is just creating more confusion. Just read the update.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx my answer was correct for the first question why would i get down vote whenever he changed his question.

Comment: First you said "The two states are basically the same state page-0 is the same as page-1 without parameter" thats wrong because `page-0` and `page-1` is declared as separate states. 

Second, my question was "How do I make `/` without the params stays at `page-0`?" And clearly the problem was not with the code for state itself but because there was a glitch on the controller. That's why I closed it. So adding an alternative answer to a working code is pretty not what future viewers would want to see.

Comment: Regarding your *Update*. The question was not wrong but the problem was not with the state code itself so you should not create an alternative for a working code.

Comment: "my answer goes to folks who kind of had the same problem the question describes". Again there is no "real" problem with the code in the question above. So why would you (again) create an alternative solution for a working code?